# How to get the n-th largest number by sas sql

Tags: sql, sas

Here is the data:

```
data bonus1;
infile cards;
input ID Amt;
cards;
1 123
2 748
3 355
4 3223
5 124
6 11
;
run;
```

I want to get the second largest amt.
I have already finish it and my code is:

```
proc sql;
create table bonus1_ans as
select max(amt)
from bonus1
where amt not in 
(select max(amt) from bonus1);
quit;
```

This structure works when I just want to get the second largest, but if I want to get the n-th largest, it is not efficient because there will be too mant nested queries.

I tried some better structure, but it seems that SAS SQL does not support limit, fetch and top, so my tries failed.

Could you help me to make a more universal code?

Answer (score 1):

Step outside of SQL then, and also think about ties.

```
data bonus1;
infile cards;
input ID Amt;
cards;
1 123
2 748
3 355
4 3223
5 124
6 11
;
run;

*second largest value;
proc sort data=bonus1; by descending amt; run;

data want;
set bonus1 (firstobs=2 obs=2);
run;

*but what about ties;
data bonus1;
infile cards;
input ID Amt;
cards;
1 123
2 748
3 355
4 3223
5 3223
6 11
;
run;

*second largest value;
proc sort data=bonus1; by descending amt; run;

data want_ties;
set bonus1;
by descending amt;
retain count 0;

if first.amt then count+1;
if count=2 then do;
output;
stop;
end;
run;

*Generates Top/Botton N Values;
ods select none;;
ods output extremevalues=want_uni;
proc univariate data=bonus1 nextrval=2;
   var AMT;
run;
ods select all;
proc print data=want_uni;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Proc RANK` will compute k<sup>th</sup> sequence position.  Is there a reason you need SQL?

```
proc rank data=bonus1 descending out=amt_rank(where=(amt_n=4));
  var amt;
  ranks amt_n;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SAS SQL, there is a solution, though it uses an undocumented function that is not supported - `monotonic()`.  It also requires creating a table, because `order` cannot be used anywhere other than the very last statement, and won't work properly in a view.

```
data bonus1;
infile cards;
input ID Amt;
cards;
1 123
2 748
3 355
4 3223
5 124
6 11
;
run;

proc sql;
  create table t_bonus_ord as 
    select id, amt
    from bonus1
    order by amt desc
  ;
  select id, amt
    from t_bonus_ord        
    where monotonic() =4
  ;
quit;
```

`monotonic` just returns 1,2,3,4, etc. and can be used similarly to the `_n_` variable in the data step - but only can be used in limited circumstances, generally a straight select from a dataset, if you want reliable results.

I would say though that I prefer Reeza's various options in general - SAS SQL is able to do this, but there're better ways.